# Reading endless XML fragments from Linux FIFO file using XmlReader and Reactive

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, system.reactive, named-pipes

I am trying to read endless XML fragments come from FIFO, and convert it to `IObservable<T>` by using `XmlReader` on Linux.

My sample code below works on .NET Core 2. But `XmlReader.ReadToFollowing` method does not return "false" (blocked), even if all resources have released.

How do I fix and call an `OnCompleted`?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly XmlReaderSettings XmlReaderSettings =
            new XmlReaderSettings {ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment /*Async = true, CloseInput = true*/};

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fifoPath = "/tmp/fifo";

            using (var fifoStream = new FileStream(fifoPath, FileMode.Open))
            using (var fifoReader = new StreamReader(fifoStream))
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fifoReader, XmlReaderSettings))
            {
                var disposable = GetObservable(xmlReader)
                    .SubscribeOn(new EventLoopScheduler())
                    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine,() => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted called."));

                Console.ReadLine();
                disposable.Dispose();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IObservable<string> GetObservable(XmlReader xmlReader)
        {
            return Observable.Create<string>(o =>
            {
                while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("item"))
                {
                    // Actually, parse item element and return it.
                    o.OnNext("OnNext item.");
                }

                o.OnCompleted();
                Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted.");

                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Repro steps
1. Make fifo. `mkfifo /tmp/fifo`
2. Run sample code.
3. Simulate endless xml. `echo "<item/><item/><item/>" > /tmp/fifo`
4. Press any key. Not show "OnCompleted".

Comment: `o.OnCompleted();` will never be called if your XML file is truly endless.

Comment: If ever you do a `return Disposable.Empty;` then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: My expected behavior is `OnCompleted()` calls after pressing any key once. Because of all resources(stream, reader and subscriber) has been disposed by `using` scope.

Comment: @idubnori - I would expect you to get an object disposed error. It's certainly not going to do what you think it will.

Comment: Also, try this query: `var source = Observable.Using(() => new FileStream(fifoPath, FileMode.Open), fifoStream => Observable.Using(() => new StreamReader(fifoStream), fifoReader => Observable.Using(() => XmlReader.Create(fifoReader, XmlReaderSettings), xmlReader => Observable.While(() => xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("item"), Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()))))));`.

Comment: @idubnori - Tell me if you can get that query working. It replaces most of your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for your code. checked. But I guess this has not release resources. Because `echo "<item>foo</item>" > /tmp/fifo` was not blocked even if subscriber had been disposed.

Comment: @idubnori - No, it releases the resources. Your expectations of what should happen are wrong,